# Swift 1.2 assigning let after initialization

Tags: swift, let

I'm trying to assign a value to a `let` in Swift 1.2 and its causing a compile error.  On Apple's blog it says that this is now allowed

> The new rule is that a let constant must be initialized before use (like a var), and that it may only be initialized, not reassigned or mutated after initialization.

So in my code i made a let a property in my class

```
class SampleClass: NSObject {
    let idOfSomething:String

    public func createSomething(idString:String)-> Void {
        self.idOfSomething = idString

    }

}
```

After I get this far the compiler complains that I cannot assign to self

here is a snapshot of the error, anyone understand what i'm doing wrong?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement you're referring to is valid for local and global variables, not for properties, for which the old rule applies: they must all be initialized either inline or in an initializer (unless it's a mutable optional property, which is automatically initialized to nil).

Comment: actually local *and* global variables - updated the answer including that :)

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing was *never* legal, and it still isn't. This is a `let` property. You cannot assign to it; it is a constant, meaning that its value can never change.

The only way you can give it its *initial* value (the only value it will ever have) is as its default or during initialization, i.e. in an initializer — and `public func createSomething` is not an initializer.

Comment: From your question, indeed, it seems as if you do not understand even what initialization _is_. You might want to read my book's discussion of this topic: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_initializers

Comment: What if you're assigning the variable in a fallible initializer and the error still appears like so? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570355/assigning-let-variable-in-fallible-initializer-swift-1-2?noredirect=1#comment47290521_29570355

Comment: @jason328 I've gone ahead and answered that one - hope it helps.