# Assigning let variable in fallible initializer swift 1.2

Tags: ios, swift, initializer

I have a struct with a fallible initializer, not an instance method, but an initializer. After updating to 1.2, when I try to assign a `let` property inside the initializer, I receive the following error `Cannot assign to 'aspectRatio' in self`. My code below:

```
import Foundation

public struct MediaItem
{
public let url: NSURL!
public let aspectRatio: Double

public var description: String { return (url.absoluteString ?? "no url") + " (aspect ratio = \(aspectRatio))" }

// MARK: - Private Implementation

init?(data: NSDictionary?) {
    var valid = false
    if let urlString = data?.valueForKeyPath(TwitterKey.MediaURL) as? NSString {
        if let url = NSURL(string: urlString as String) {
            self.url = url
            let h = data?.valueForKeyPath(TwitterKey.Height) as? NSNumber
            let w = data?.valueForKeyPath(TwitterKey.Width) as? NSNumber
            if h != nil && w != nil && h?.doubleValue != 0 {
                aspectRatio = w!.doubleValue / h!.doubleValue
                valid = true
            }
        }
    }
    if !valid {
        return nil
    }
}

struct TwitterKey {
    static let MediaURL = "media_url_https"
    static let Width = "sizes.small.w"
    static let Height = "sizes.small.h"
}
}
```

My question is what do I do to fix this?

Comment: Isn't this just because you have an immutable variable (with `let`) and you're assigning to it twice (once in the initialiser - 0, and another time in the constructor) - does it work if you only assign to it in the constructor and assign 0 in an `else`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift 1.2 assigning let after initialization](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29564272/swift-1-2-assigning-let-after-initialization)

Comment: @Benjamin, I'm now getting `self used before all stored properties are initialized` after adding the else statement and removing the initializer.

Comment: @Riley, what is the difference between that question and mine? I'm using a fallible initializer and that question is not.

Comment: Upvoted for supplying all the code necessary for me to just copy and paste it into an app and try to compile it and duplicate your issue. I wish everyone who asked a question would do that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Swift 1.2 has closed a loophole having to do with `let` properties:

> The new rule is that a let constant must be initialized before use (like a var), and that it may only be initialized, not reassigned or mutated after initialization.

That rule is exactly what you are trying to violate. `aspectRatio` is a `let` property *and you have already given it a value* in its declaration:

```
public let aspectRatio: Double = 0
```

So before we ever get to the initializer, `aspectRatio` has its initial value — 0. And that is the only value it can ever have. The new rule means that you can *never* assign to `aspectRatio` ever again, *not even in an initializer*.

The solution is (and this was always the right way): assign it *no* value in its declaration:

```
public let aspectRatio: Double
```

Now, in the initializer, *either* assign it 0 *or* assign it `w!.doubleValue / h!.doubleValue`. In other words, take care of *every* possibility in the initializer, *once*. That will be the *only* time, one way or another, that you get to assign `aspectRatio` a value.

If you think about it, you'll realize that this is a much more sensible and consistent approach; previously, you were sort of prevaricating on the meaning of `let`, and the new rule has stopped you, rightly, from doing that.

---

In your rewrite of the code, you are failing to initialize all properties in the situation where you intend to bail out and return `nil`. I know it may seem counterintuitive, but you cannot do that. You must initialize all properties *even if* you intend to bail out. I discuss this very clearly [in my book](http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/ch04.html#_class_initializers):

> A failable class initializer cannot say `return nil` until after it has completed all of its own initialization duties. Thus, for example, a failable subclass designated initializer must see to it that all the subclass’s properties are initialized and must call `super.init(...)` before it can say `return nil`. (There is a certain delicious irony here: before it can tear the instance down, the initializer must finish building the instance up.)

**EDIT:** Please note that starting in Swift 2.2, this requirement will be lifted. It will be legal to `return nil` *before* initializing properties. This will put class initializers on a par with struct initializers, where this was already legal.

Comment: This makes sense to me, however I'm still getting this error. `self used before all stored properties are initialized`. Am I right to assume this an entirely different problem? Thanks for the help so far.

Comment: @jason328 The problem is that I don't know what your _new_ code looks like. I've explained the problem with the code you showed in your question. I don't know what change you made to it that is getting you this other problem.

Comment: My apoligizes. Question is now updated to reflect most current code.

Comment: With the new code, you didn't take care of all possibilities like you have to in an initializer. You do some stuff in the conditions `if let urlString = ...` and `if let url = ...`. But what if those things are _not_ true? Then those conditions are not, that code never executes — and `url` and `aspectRatio` are never initialized. But you _must_ initialize them! That is what the error message is telling you. You must cover _all_ possibilities.

Comment: Oh, I left something out. You must do that _even if_ you are then going to return nil to mark failure. It sounds wacky, but it is the only way to ensure perfect consistency.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation without giving me the answer directly. Simply copying and pasting will not help me understand why this error is occurring and you've done an excellent job at explaining this issue.