# Swift gives "self used before all stored procedures are initialized" error when building child nodes

Tags: swift, self

In XCode 6.2, I have a Swift project where a main-object ("Backbone") creates sub-objects with pointers back to Backbone:

```
class Backbone
{
    let logManager: QCLogManager!
    let cloudJobManager: CloudJobManager!
    ...

    init() {
        logManager = QCLogManager(backbone: self)
        cloudJobManager = CloudJobManager(backbone: self)
        ...
    }
```

It works very nicely. However, in XCode 6.3 each line in `init()` now gives the error:

> 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized.

That seems a rather unhelpful compiler restriction. Why did it change? How should I now be doing it?

Comment: See this link updated with Swift 1.2
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570355/assigning-let-variable-in-fallible-initializer-swift-1-2

Answer (score 1):

```
let logManager: QCLogManager!
let cloudJobManager: CloudJobManager!
```

if `let` is not necessary, change to `var`

```
var logManager: QCLogManager!
var cloudJobManager: CloudJobManager!
```

Comment: But `Backbone.logManager` should be immutable, so I want to use `let`. Making it mutable just to save a line of code seems like a bad trade.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to create a property of type `Backbone` in both `QCLogManager` and `CloudJobManager` and set that property after initialization of all store properties of BackBone class.

```
class Backbone
{
    let logManager: QCLogManager!
    let cloudJobManager: CloudJobManager!
    ...

    init() {
        logManager = QCLogManager()
        cloudJobManager = CloudJobManager()
        ...
        logManager.backBone = self
        cloudJobManager.backBone = self
    }
```

Comment: Yes, that certainly works. I'm still hoping there might be a cleaner way to do it, but perhaps that's no longer possible. Thanks.