# 'self' used before all stored properties are initialized

Tags: swift, initialization, swift2

I'm working through a [learn-swift playground](https://github.com/nettlep/learn-swift/blob/master/16.%20ARC.playground/section-1.swift#L216) and upgrading it to Swift 2.0 as I learn the language.  The following code (which likely worked with prior versions of Swift) now generates two errors: "'self' used before all stored properties are initialized" and "Constant 'self.capitalCity' used before initialized"

```
class Country
{
    let name: String
    let capitalCity: City!

    init(name: String, capitalName: String)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.capitalCity = City(name: capitalName, country: self)
    }
}

class City
{
    let name: String
    unowned let country: Country

    init(name: String, country: Country)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.country = country
    }
}
```

reading an [answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29761219/swift-gives-self-used-before-all-stored-procedures-are-initialized-error-when) I see that I can change `let capitalCity: City!` to `var capitalCity: City!` and the syntax error is resolved.

I realize that in this contrived example a country's capital city can change, so that would be fine, but what if there were a case where the value really was a constant...

Is there any way to resolve the syntax error while keeping capitalCity a constant?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

In this case I would suggest you to make the property a variable but hiding it (make it seem like a constant) through a computed property:

```
class Country {
    let name: String

    private var _capitalCity: City!
    var capitalCity: City {
        return _capitalCity
    }

    init(name: String, capitalName: String) {
        self.name = name
        self._capitalCity = City(name: capitalName, country: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: this is a great answer.  It gets to the interface that I wanted, though the explanation by @matt was fabulous

Comment: swift is a  weird language for initialization.

Comment: This did not work for me. It fixed the compile error, but when I pass self to the constructor of another object, and then that object calls a function on self, that function sees an entirely different (uninitialized) self.

Comment: @svenyonson Only `capitalCity` is not initialized when calling the constructor of `City`. If you want to use it inside the constructor, then you have to use `self` inside the `City` constructor. If the problem is complicated then feel free to ask a question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 32):

> Is there any way to resolve the syntax error while keeping `capitalCity` a constant?

Not the way you have things set up. The source of the problem is actually that in order to set `capitalCity`, you have to create a City whose `country` is `self`. *That* is the use of `self` to which the compiler is objecting:

```
self.capitalCity = City(name: capitalName, country: self)
                                                    ^^^^
```

Since you have configured City's `country` as a constant, you *must* supply this value when you initialize your City. Thus you have no way out; you must make `capitalCity` an Optional `var` so that it has some *other* initial value that is legal, namely `nil`. Your proposed solution actually works like this:

```
class Country
{
    let name: String
    var capitalCity: City! = nil // implicit or explicit

    init(name: String, capitalName: String)
    {
        self.name = name
        // end of initialization!
        // name is set (to name), and capitalCity is set (to nil)...
        // ... and so the compiler is satisfied;
        // now, we _change_ capitalCity from nil to an actual City,
        // and in doing that, we _are_ allowed to mention `self`
        self.capitalCity = City(name: capitalName, country: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: what about memory leak?

Comment: @user3441734 That is the problem that `unowned` solves.

Comment: @matt: You could also declare `capitalCity` prefixing `private(set)` in order to prevent external changes of the variable.

Comment: @appzYourLife Sure, but that wouldn't change the fact that, given the structural relation between the two classes, `capitalCity` must be an Optional `var` in order to satisfy the compiler that the object is being correctly initialized — which is what the question was. "Is there any way to resolve the syntax error while keeping capitalCity a constant?" No.

Comment: @matt: yes, I know it must be an Optional `var`. I was just proposing to change the property declaration in your solution to `private(set) var capitalCity: City! = nil`. Right now infact some code external to your definition of `Country` could set `capitalCity = nil` which is dangerous for an implicitly unwrapped optional property.

Comment: @appzYourLife Fine, then give that as an answer! I'll upvote it. But in fact the other answer (from Qbyte) has already shown how to prevent that. But _my_ answer stands. The OP didn't ask how to prevent someone else from changing `capitalCity`; I answered the question the OP _did_ ask.

Comment: FYI. For cross reference in the Swift Programming Language, see _Unowned References and Implicitly Unwrapped Optional Properties_ section: `var capitalCity: City!` is ["an implicitly unwrapped optional property … that … has a default value of nil"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

Answer (score 26):

Just do:

```
private(set) var capitalCity: City!
```

which gives you the read-only public interface you want.

I understand that you find `var capitalCity: City!` contrived.  I'd say that [the selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34474695/1971013) is truly contrived; it adds lines of code that have no purpose other than resolving a language-related issue. Lines like that are meaningless and *meaning* is what *matters* most in code.

Comment: This should be the selected answer

Comment: This should be the selected answer +1

Answer (score 1):

Came across this recently while struggling with a similar problem and as of swift 5.5 (or possibly lower) there is another alternative that is interesting.  If you convert Capital City to a `lazy var` you are actually able to use self in initialization.

```
class Country
{
    let name: String

    lazy var capitalCity: City = {
        City(name: capitalName, country: self)
    }()

    private let capitalName: String

    init(name: String, capitalName: String)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.capitalName = capitalName
    }
}

class City
{
    let name: String
    unowned let country: Country

    init(name: String, country: Country)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.country = country
    }
}
```

Cheers!